# How to combine two conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two conditions:

```
x = Equipment.last.try(:category_id) # => 1
y = WantedEquipment.pluck(:category_id) # => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 
y.include? x # => true

Equipment.last.try(:sub_category_id) # => 2 
b = WantedEquipment.pluck(:sub_category_id) # => [3, 3, 2, 2, 2] 
b.include? a # => true
```

I am trying to apply them both. I tried:

```
y.include? x && b.include? a 
do ...

end
```

Could somebody tell me what the right way is to do this?

Comment: you do it correctly. But make sure to use `()`: `y.include?(x) && b.include?(a) `

Comment: You mean this ` y.include? x && b.include? a `  is right?  @AndreyDeineko

Comment: The idea is right, the syntax should be corrected. See more details in @ndn's answer

Comment: What is `a` in `b.include? a`?

Answer (score 7):

```
y.include? x && b.include? a
```

Will confuse the interpreter as to when to do the `&&` and the method invocations. Instead, just place the brackets yourself:

```
y.include?(x) && b.include?(a)
```

Comment: I added the brackets and removed the space. It's working.